# Do Redemption API support unicode characters when creating pst from email message files?

Tags: outlook-redemption

I have an email messages file having unicode characters in the body. When I created a pst for that message file and loaded it in outlook, body text is entirely missing.
Do redemption api supports unicode characters when creating pst from email message file?

**UPDATE 1**

Below is the code for creating PST

```
        private static void CreatePSTUsingRedemption(XmlNodeList nodelist, string pstPath)
        {            
          RDOSession pstSession = null;
          RDOPstStore store = null;
          RDOFolder folder = null;
          RDOMail rdo_Mail = null;
          RDOItems items = null;
          string processingFileId = string.Empty;
          SafeMailItem sitem = new SafeMailItem();
          try
          {
              pstSession = new RDOSession();
              store = pstSession.LogonPstStore(pstPath, 1, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pstPath));
              int completedCount = 0;
              folder = store.IPMRootFolder;
              RDOFolder inboxFolder = pstSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
              inboxFolder.Delete();
              RDOFolder sentFolder = pstSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
              sentFolder.Delete();
              RDOFolder outboxFolder = pstSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
              outboxFolder.Delete();
              folder = folder.Folders.Add("Messages");
              foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
              {
                  processingFileId = node["Id"].InnerText;
                  RemoteSharedInfo rI = XmlUtil.GetObjectFromXmlString<RemoteSharedInfo>(node["RemoteSharedInfo"].OuterXml);
                  using (FileShareImpersonator imp = new FileShareImpersonator(rI))
                  {
                      imp.Start();
                      if (node["OriginalFileExtension"].InnerText.ToLower() == "eml" || node["OriginalFileExtension"].InnerText.ToLower() == "emlx")
                       {
                          items = folder.Items;
                          rdo_Mail = items.Add("IPM.Note");
                          sitem.Item = items.Add(0);
                          sitem.Import(node["FullPath"].InnerText, 0x400);
                          sitem.CopyTo(rdo_Mail);
                          rdo_Mail.Save();
                          store.Save();
                          completedCount++;
                          Console.WriteLine("FILES_PROCESSED:" + completedCount);
                      }
                      else //go to this ELSE block for email message files i.e for msg extension
                      {
                          rdo_Mail = pstSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(node["FullPath"].InnerText);
                          rdo_Mail.CopyTo(folder);
                          rdo_Mail.Save();
                          store.Save();
                          completedCount++;
                          Console.WriteLine("FILES_PROCESSED:" + completedCount);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.Message);
            Environment.ExitCode = 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdo_Mail);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sitem);
            if (items != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items);
        }
        pstSession.Logoff();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pstSession);
        GC.Collect();
        Environment.ExitCode = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Redemption is fully Unicode enabled. Make sire you are creating a Unicode PST file.

What is your code creating the PST file? What is the exact version f Outlook?

Comment: Hello Dmitry, I have updated my question by adding the code for PST creation and also the version of outlook that I am using is 2013.

Comment: Are you having problems with EML or MSG files?

Comment: For the MSG files, why are you using GetMessageFromMsgFile / CopyTo instead of Import(..., olMsg)?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with msg file. I found this code somewhere on the internet. Do import function gets the message file and copies it to the current folder? And what will be the value of 'type' if the message has Unicode characters? What about eml file? Is it the correct way to process using redemption?

Comment: Import function imports into the given message, not a folder directly. Both ANSI and Unicode MSG files can be processed by Import (..., olMsg).

Comment: How to initialize rdo_mail object? It is null when calling the import function.

Comment: I went through the Redemption document, got a bit confused. My requirement is to get a combined pst from msg and eml files. Could you please provide some reference (GitHub link or any documentation) that will help me accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you saying items.Add returns null?

Comment: No. If I use import instead of  GetMessageFromMsgFile / CopyTo then how can I initialize rdo_Mail object for msg files?

Comment: You don't - you create a new message using Items.Add, then import an MSG file using Import. Just like yo udo when processing the MIME (EML) files.

Comment: Ok. I will make the changes accordingly. Thank you, Dmitry.